# Cross-referencing between chapters

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a thesis. In the main file of the thesis, I have included `\usepackage{xr}`. Then in Chapter2, I have included `\externaldocument{./Chapters/Chapter1}` to get access of equations of Chapter1. But I cant. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: If you include the chapters with `\include` you don't need `xr` package at all. Do you have `\label`s at all?

Comment: In the main chapter, I have used \usepackage{xr}. Then called two chapters \input{./Chapters/Chapter1} and \input{./Chapters/Chapter2}. Then to get access of equations of Chapter1 from Chapter2, I have just included \externaldocument{./Chapters/Chapter1} in the header of Chapter2. Nothing else. Now, how can I get access to the equations of Chapter 1 from Chapter2?

Comment: Nasim, this procedure is wrong, sorry

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xr` package is not meant to get references from external files that are included anyway -- it works, but it will complain about the multiply defined labels (unless the optional argument of `\externaldocument` is used.

Rather use `\include` or `\input`. This way the content of files are included and the references are correct anyway!

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}

In \ref{eq:first} and \ref{eq:second} we will see that

\include{chapterone}


\include{chaptertwo}
\end{document}
```

`chapterone.tex`:

```
\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eq:first}
\end{equation}
```

`chaptertwo.tex`

```
\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{equation}
  c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \label{eq:second}
\end{equation}
```

Other way (but not really useful!):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xr}

\externaldocument[Aext]{chapterone}

\externaldocument[Bext]{chaptertwo}

\begin{document}

In \ref{eq:first} and \ref{eq:second} we will see that

\include{chapterone}


\include{chaptertwo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Nasim: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 1):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{chapter1.tex}
    \chapter{foo}\label{chap:foo}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chapter2.tex}
    \chapter{bar}\label{chap:bar}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}

See chapter \ref{chap:foo} and \ref{chap:bar}

\end{document}
```